# Using ntile from dplyr within an ifelse statement

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, data.table

I'm trying to segment some data using ntile (from dplyr) into 'n' equal buckets separately for negative and positive values in the same data.table column.

I'll demonstrate what I mean via a simple example:

```
require(data.table)
require(dplyr)
Buckets <- 3

Check <- data.table(a = sample(-30:30,30))
Check[a < 0,Test := ntile(a[a < 0],Buckets) * -1]
Check[a >= 0,Test := ntile(a[a >= 0],Buckets)]
```

When I perform a test to see whether the buckets are OK (i.e. not overlapping), you can see that it checks out:

```
Check[,range(a),by = Test][order(Test)]
```

I want to combine the above into one ifelse statement within the data.table "Check" as, in practice, I will be performing these calculations over multiple columns and the rows which are greater than or less than 0 will differ by column. I'd therefore prefer to operate solely on columns rather than subsetting by rows separately as per the original code and repeating it for each column.

When I try to do the following, it doesn't seem to identify the rows that I would have expected when calling the 'ntile' function:

```
Check[,Test := ifelse(a < 0,
                 ntile(a[a < 0],Buckets)*-1,
                 ntile(a[a >= 0],Buckets))]
```

Perform check again:

```
Check[,range(a),by = Test][order(Test)]
```

Which doesn't check out...

Can anyone please let me know what I'm missing and whether it's possible to utilise 'ifelse' here? Any other approaches are also welcome as I'm always keen to learn new things.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: The `ifelse` needs all arguments to have same length.  Here `a < 0` should have the whole length of the column `a[a < 0]` not that  or `a[a >=0]`. May be you need to create a group by `ntile` or a nested `ifelse`

Comment: @Akrun, I tried the following, but it doesn't seem to work. 
                  Check[,Test := ifelse(a < 0, ntile(a,Buckets)*-1, 
                                          ifelse(a >= 0, ntile(a,Buckets), 0))] 
Can you please explain what you mean by creating a group by ntile?

Comment: The ``ifelse`` may not be necessary. How about something like this ``Check[,Test_2 := ntile(a, 2 * Buckets) - Buckets]`` ? If having a bucket name 0 is a problem for some reason you can always go for ``Check[Test_2 == 0, 'Test_2'] <- -3``

Comment: @Phil Instead of `ifelse`, you can also pass two arguments to `Map` and get the output i.e. `Check[, Test_2 := unsplit(Map(function(x, y) ntile(x, Buckets) * y, split(a, a < 0), c(1, -1)), a < 0)]`

Comment: That's awesome - thanks for that. I've used the map function solution.